# The Submenu won't open exactly under parent menu

Tags: html, css

When i hover over the menu point, the submenu will open on the left, not right under his parent menu point. 
I already tried to change the position attributes, but I can't find the right way to do this.
The best i got was that the menu moved to the right when i changed block to inline-block.
Is there a way doing it without any javascript?

```css
nav {
  background-color: cadetblue;
  position: relative;
  height: 60px;
}

ul.fixed {
  background-color: cadetblue;
  font-size: 22px;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
}

ul.fixed li {
  display: inline;
  list-style: none;
  font-family: Bahnschrift;
}

ul.fixed li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: aliceblue;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 20px;
}

ul.fixed li a:hover {
  background-color: gray;
  color: cornflowerblue;
  opacity: .8;
}

ul.Untermenue {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: gray;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding: 0;
  opacity: .8;
}

li.Untermenue {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
}

ul.Untermenue li a {
  color: #D6D6D6;
  display: block;
}

.Dropdown:hover .Untermenue {
  display: block;
}

.Untermenue a:hover {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}
```

```html
<nav class="Navigation">
  <ul class="fixed">
    <li><a href="Menü.html">Home</a></li>
    <li class="Dropdown"><a>Wir</a>
      <ul class="Untermenue">
        <li><a href="Menü.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="Menü.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="Menü.html">Home</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="Menü.html">Haus</a></li>
    <li><a href="Menü.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Interesting questions, perhaps see the hover state in the dev tools? not sure.

Comment: The parent `li` needs to be `position:relative`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try update your css with below code

CSS

```
ul.Untermenue {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: gray;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding: 0;
    opacity: .8;
    left: 0;     /* Newly added class */
}

ul.fixed li {
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
    font-family: Bahnschrift;
    position:relative; /* Newly added class */
}
```

OUTPUT

[image]

Comment: I just realised my answer is pretty much identical to yours Par Tha _ upvoting yours & deleting mine ; )